# opencv calls in shared library segfaults when used through python ctypes

Tags: c++, python, gcc, opencv, ctypes

Whenever I load a shared library (.so) into Python with ctypes and call one of it's procedures that uses the OpenCV filter engine (like cvErode or cvDilate), the interpreter segfaults deep inside the OpenCV code.
If I load the same library with dlopen inside a C program and call the same procedure everything works fine.

I've read in another post that it might have to do with the ABI that gcc utilizes and that python has to be compiled with the same version of gcc that the python interpreter was compiled with for this to work. However in my case it's both 4.4.5 so that shouldn't be an issue. The OpenCV libraries were also compiled with that same version of gcc.

How the shared library is built:

```
g++ -g -shared -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_ml -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -o thumbsplit.so thumbsplit.cpp
```

How the shared library is wrapped:

```
extern "C" {

int is_thumbsheet(char * image_path){
    Image image;
    image.read(image_path);
    int width = image.columns();
    int height = image.rows();
    int BOUND_CHANGE = 7000;
    int test_height = 0;

    if( width > height ){
        return 0;
    }else{
        test_height = width;
    }
    vector<int> test_rows = getRows(image, width, test_height, BOUND_CHANGE);
    vector<int> test_cols = getCols(image, width, test_height, BOUND_CHANGE);

    vector<Box> test_boxes = createBoxes(test_rows,test_cols,width,height);
    if( test_boxes.size() > 6 ){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int cut_thumbs(char * image_path, char * thumb_path){
    Image image;
    image.read(image_path);
    int width = image.columns();
    int height = image.rows();
    int BOUND_CHANGE = 7000;
    vector<int> rows = getRows(image, width, height, BOUND_CHANGE);
    vector<int> cols = getCols(image, width, height, BOUND_CHANGE);

    //drawDebugLines(rows, cols, width, height);

    vector<Box> boxes = createBoxes(rows,cols,width,height);
    //printBoxes(boxes);
    char path[0x100];
    for( int i=0 ; i < boxes.size() ; i++ ){
        sprintf(path, "%s%d.jpg", thumb_path, i);
        boxes[i].saveBox(image, path);
    }


    return 0;
}

} // C
```

How the shared library procedures are loaded in python:

```
import ctypes, os

def load_lib():
lib_path = "%s/%s"%(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "thumbsplit.so")
lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path)
return lib

def is_thumbsheet(image_path):

lib = load_lib()
if lib.is_thumbsheet(image_path):
    return True
else:
    return False

def cut_thumbs(image_path, thumbs_path):

lib = load_lib()
lib.cut_thumbs(image_path, thumbs_path)

is_thumbsheet("/home/rolf/test/imageproc/full9.jpg") # this segfaults
```

GDB output:

```
$ gdb python
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.0.1-debian
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i486-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/python...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run thumbsheet.py
Starting program: /usr/bin/python thumbsheet.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
0xb6330a12

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb76fe2dc in cv::FilterEngine::start(cv::Size_<int>, cv::Rect_<int>, int) () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.3
(gdb) info stack
#0  0xb76fe2dc in cv::FilterEngine::start(cv::Size_<int>, cv::Rect_<int>, int) () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.3
#1  0xb76feb41 in cv::FilterEngine::start(cv::Mat const&, cv::Rect_<int> const&, bool, int) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.3
#2  0xb770a52b in cv::FilterEngine::apply(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Rect_<int> const&, cv::Point_<int>, bool) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.3
#3  0xb764bf8a in cv::morphOp(int, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&) () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.3
#4  0xb764d2ce in cv::erode(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, int, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&) () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.3
#5  0xb764d62e in cvErode () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.3
#6  0xb7fd7adb in seperate::findSeperatedBoxes (img=0x8351d70) at seperate.cpp:189
#7  0xb7fd7fcf in seperate::trySeperatedBoxes (img=0x8351d70, percentage_boxed=0xbfffefec) at seperate.cpp:202
#8  0xb7fda00c in is_thumbsheet (image_path=0xb7c1bf74 "/home/rolf/test/imageproc/full9.jpg") at thumbsplit.cpp:39
#9  0xb7a047df in ffi_call_SYSV () from /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#10 0xb7a0461e in ffi_call () from /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#11 0xb79ff27d in _CallProc () from /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#12 0xb79f6d7e in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
#13 0x0806232a in PyObject_Call ()
#14 0x080e016b in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#15 0x080e18b0 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#16 0x080e2507 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#17 0x080e2607 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#18 0x080ffcbd in PyRun_FileExFlags ()
#19 0x080fff22 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
#20 0x0805dd81 in Py_Main ()
#21 0x0805cf6b in main ()
(gdb) x/i 0xb76fe2dc
0xb76fe2dc <_ZN2cv12FilterEngine5startENS_5Size_IiEENS_5Rect_IiEEi+1212>:   movdqa %xmm3,0x30(%esp)
(gdb)
```

GCC/G++ versions:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2

$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5

$ g++ --version
g++ (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5
```

OpenCV is version 2.3.1 and was built from source using this version of gcc (4.4.5-8)

Comment: you do realize, that there are Python bindings for OpenCV? http://code.google.com/p/pyopencv/

Comment: yeah, but I'd rather do all my image processing in c/c++ for speed reasons. Not all of it is done inside OpenCV.

Comment: IF you write a C program to load and use your library, you'll know if the problem is in your OpenCV code, or in the code that loads the library in Python.

Comment: I don't think you'll see significant speed differences. Python Image Library (PIL) is Python extension written in C.

Comment: @karlphillip: I did, that works fine. The code that loads the library is also correct as it works with other modules that don't use OpenCV.

Comment: @vartec: I'm doing some custom processing at the pixel level. I've done this in python before and it was very very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. The stack needs to be realigned to 16 bytes for SSE instructions. If I build the shared library with -mstackrealign it works perfectly loaded and called from python.

[Qt, GCC, SSE and stack alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386408/qt-gcc-sse-and-stack-alignment)